# jQuery function on $('p')[0]

Tags: jquery

I tried the script

```
$('p')[0].innerHTML = 'hi';
```

and it worked
but for slideUp/Down it does not works :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do:

```
$('p').eq(0).slideUp(); //The same for slideDown
```

Cheers

Comment: can i do it $('p').eq(1).slideUp(); ?

Comment: @Sourav. Yes, you can use any index you want. Glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

The `$('selector')[0]` syntax accesses the raw DOM elements matched by the selector. To call jQuery functions like `slideUp`, you should omit the array access operation like this: `$('p').slideUp();` If you specifically want to operate on only the first paragraph, use `$('p:first')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p:eq(0)").slideUp();// This will select first 'P' tag and slide it up. You can change the index as per your requirement.
```

to toggle it use

```
$("p:eq(0)").toggle();
```

Comment: i knew about '$('p').eq(0)' but never about '$("p:eq(0)")' +1